# No tuples is emitted or transffered by topology in storm ui

Tags: elasticsearch, web-crawler, stormcrawler

i am using stormcrawler 1.16 with elasticsearch 7.2.0. i have built project with with acrhetype.
command i run to submitted topology

```
 storm jar target/stormcrawler-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar  org.apache.storm.flux.Flux --remote es-crawler.flux
```

i am getting this in output -

```
 Parsing file: /home/ubuntu/stormcrawler/es-crawler.flux
 835  [main] INFO  o.a.s.f.p.FluxParser - loading YAML from input 
 stream...
 841  [main] INFO  o.a.s.f.p.FluxParser - Not performing property 
 substitution.
 841  [main] INFO  o.a.s.f.p.FluxParser - Not performing environment 
 variable substitution.
 900  [main] INFO  o.a.s.f.p.FluxParser - Loading includes from 
 resource: /crawler-default.yaml
 901  [main] INFO  o.a.s.f.p.FluxParser - loading YAML from input 
 stream...
 903  [main] INFO  o.a.s.f.p.FluxParser - Not performing property 
 substitution.
 903  [main] INFO  o.a.s.f.p.FluxParser - Not performing environment 
 variable substitution.
 Configuration (interpreted):
```

then i last output lines -

```
   2014 [main] WARN  o.a.s.u.Utils - STORM-VERSION new 1.2.3 old 1.2.3
   2376 [main] INFO  o.a.s.StormSubmitter - Finished submitting topology: crawler
```

but when i check this crawler topology in storm ui, then in  topology stats, no tuple is emitted or transffered by this crawler topology.

i have atteched a snapshot of storm ui in link below.

[in topology stats, no tuples is emitted or transffered. how can i solve this issue ? [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tHYqs.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your POM file is probably missing the *storm-crawler-elasticsearch* dependency.

You could compare your code with what is generated by the *storm-crawler-elasticsearch-archetype*, which should give you a working configuration.

> Use the archetype for Elasticsearch with:
>
> mvn archetype:generate
>   -DarchetypeGroupId=com.digitalpebble.stormcrawler -DarchetypeArtifactId=storm-crawler-elasticsearch-archetype -DarchetypeVersion=LATEST
>
> You'll be asked to enter a groupId (e.g. com.mycompany.crawler), an
>   artefactId (e.g. stormcrawler), a version and package name.
>
> This will not only create a fully formed project containing a POM with
>   the dependency above but also a set of resources, configuration files
>   and a topology class. Enter the directory you just created (should be
>   the same as the artefactId you specified earlier) and follow the
>   instructions on the README file.

Comment: pom.xml file has _storm-crawler-elasticsearch_ dependency. and i have followed the README.md file instructions . still i am getting this error.

Comment: thanks! did you generate the project using the archetype? if you open the jar file, can you see the class     com.digitalpebble.stormcrawler.elasticsearch.persistence.AggregationSpout?
BTW you should specify --sleep when running in local mode, otherwise the topology will run only for a short duration.
Could you share your pom and flux files? Thanks!

Comment: thanks sir ! it worked. now topology is submitted successfully. now the issue is that no crawling is happening. i put 3 urls in seeds.txt file. crawler topology is shown in storm ui but in topology stats, no tuple is emitted or transferred by crawler topology. i am working in remote mode. i think topology is not injecting the urls to elasticsearch. please help !

Comment: what was the problem with AggregationSpout? did you use the archetype?

Comment: I was using archetype command with 1.16 version. When i run command with version 'latest' then it works. Now issue is the same i mentioned in previous comment. I think crawler topology is not getting urls from seeds.txt file. Injection part of topology is not working . How can i check if injection is working or not ? Can i use es-injector.flux file of version 1.15 ? Will it work ?

Comment: you can check the content of the status index using Kibana or on localhost:9200/status/_search
If the file is relative in Flux, you probably need to run it locally so that the topology finds it e.g. --local es-crawler.flux --sleep 86400000